# What's the idiomatic way in Java8 to do something parallel that requires a non-thread-safe helper object?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have some code like this

```
public List doSomething(List stuff) {
  ArrayList out = new ArrayList();
  BigNonThreadSafeObject bntso = new BigNonThreadSafeObject();
  for(Thing t: stuff)
    out.add(bntso.doSomethingComplicated(t));
  return out;
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this `for` loop in parallel (to take advantage of multi-core processing) in Java8?

The trick of course is how do you initialize a separate `BigNonThreadSafeObject` for each worker thread without having to jump through hoops with `ThreadLocal` etc?

Comment: If your object is not thread safe, no amount of API helpers etc will help you there; your only real option is to either make your object thread safe or redo it as a `Collector`, for instance.

Comment: ThreadLocal seems like the appropriate way of having one object per thread. Why do you consider it as "jumping through hoops"? Note that a lot of thread-unsafe objects can be used concurrently if their state is never modified (like an ArrayList, for example). And I guess that could be the case, otherwise creating multiple objects instead of just one wouldn't lead to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to have a separate object for each thread is to use `ThreadLocal`. However, this means that all the threads in the `ForkJoinPool` will retain their copy of `BigNonThreadSafeObject` until the thread terminates. That doesn't sound very good, unless you're doing this parallel map often and always on the same set of threads.

You could try an object pool like [commons-pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/), and in your `map()` do check out->work with bntso->check in. However, if the "work" step is fast then contention on the pool will eat up any gains you might get from parallelizing. It's clunky, but you can expect any solution to be clunky. Pipelines were designed for each instance of an operation to be independent of all the other instances, and once an instance cares what thread it's running on you're violating that assumption.